# Adjoint operator of a partial differential operator used to do the carleman estimate

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, inner-products, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I am reading [Carleman estimate for parabolic equations and applications](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231017413_Carleman_estimates_for_parabolic_equations_and_applications) written by Masahiro Yamamoto.
Let $P$ be an operator defined by
$$
Pw=\partial_tw-\Delta w+2s\nabla \varphi\cdot\nabla w+(-s\partial_t \varphi-s^2|\nabla\varphi|^2+s\Delta \varphi)w.
$$
The article on page 4 says that the way is the decomposition of $P$ into the symmetric part $P_+$ and antisymmetric part $P_-$. To do this, he consider the formal ajoint operator $P^*$ to $P$:
$$
(Pw,v)_{L^2(D)}=(w,P^*v)_{L^2(D)},\quad v,w\in C_0^\infty(D).
$$
By integration by parts, the Green's theorem and $v,w \in C_0^\infty(D)$, he obtains
$$
P^*=-\partial_t w-\Delta w -2s\nabla\varphi\cdot\nabla w-(s\Delta \varphi+s^2|\nabla\varphi|^2+s(\partial_t\varphi))w.
$$
It can be seen that the term $s\Delta\varphi w$ change to $-s\Delta \varphi w$. I cannot figure out why this change happens. According to my understanding (may not be true),
$$
(s\Delta \varphi w,v)=(w,s\Delta \varphi v),
$$
so there must be something wrong with my thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the part $w\mapsto s(\Delta \phi)w$ is symmetric. However, there is additionally a contribution from the part $w\mapsto 2s\nabla \phi\cdot\nabla w$:
$$
\int v\nabla\phi\cdot\nabla w=-\int w\nabla\cdot(v\nabla \phi)=-\int w(\nabla v\cdot\nabla \phi+v\Delta \phi).
$$
So you end up with $s(\Delta \phi)w-2s(\Delta \phi)w=-s (\Delta \phi)w$ in the adjoint.